# Symfony 2 persiting 2 entities from form using ID generated from first entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a form that collects data from two related entities 'Jobs' and 'Scope'. Jobs data adds successfully to the database, but i can't get the scope entity to add which also requires the unique ID that was created from the jobs entry. I'm using doctrine by the way.

Here is jobsType:

```
class jobsType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('jobNumber', null,  array('label' => 'Job Number','attr' => array('placeholder'=>'Code used for job')))

        ->add('description', null,  array('label' => 'Job Description',))

        ;

        $builder->add('scopes', new scopeType())
        ;

    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'jobs';
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'Baker\TimeSlipBundle\Entity\Jobs',
        ));
    }

}
```

Here is scopeType

```
    class scopeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder

        ->add('description', 'entity', array('label' => 'Scope', 'required' => false,
                'class' => 'BakerTimeSlipBundle:Scope',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                    ->orderBy('s.description', 'asc');
                },
                'property' => 'description',
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
                'empty_value' => false,
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-inline'),
                'label_attr' => array('class' => 'required')
        ))

        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'Baker\TimeSlipBundle\Entity\Scope',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'scope';
    }
}
```

Here is my controller, i think the problem here is that i'm not passing the scope() instance to the form builder. Which i'm not sure how to do. The entity is mapped correctly.

```
class JobsController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction($limit, Request $request)
    {

        $jobs= new Jobs();
        $scope = new Scope();   

        $fname=$limit;
        $form = $this->createForm(new JobsType(),$jobs, array(
                'method' => 'POST',
        ));
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                        $em->persist($jobs);
                        $em->persist($scope);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('company',array ('limit' =>'Job Submitted Successfully'));
        }


        return $this->render(
                'BakerTimeSlipBundle:Jobs:index.html.twig',
                array('fname' => $fname,
                        'form' => $form->createView()

                )
        );

        }
    }
}
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Below is listed the error message  when I try to enter the scope:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Scope (description, jobsId, jobsid) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null]:
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1110 Column 'jobsId' specified twice

Comment: Certainly not related but you should have your form handling the request only `if($request->isMethod('POST')) {}`. Also, you should retrieve `$jobs` by doing `$jobs = $form->getData();`.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i thought to allow doctrine to handle the dependencies you have to use   $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the $jobs object you link to your form has no relation with the $scope object. So when you try to persist $jobs, Doctrine has no idea $scope it had to persist.

Just try this :

```
$jobs= new Jobs();
$scope = new Scope();
$jobs->setScope($scope);
```

Then, in your Jobs entity, on the annotation above $scopes, make sure you have `cascade={"persist"}` (but you must already have it because Doctrine tries to persist, and that's where the error is thrown), and you should be good to go.

Hope this helps

Comment: hmm, i don't have any setScope method. Where should this be created?

Comment: Your Job entity should have the standard getters and setters for the scope property. If not, add them. And more generaly, check out every property of every entity has its getters and setters.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the correct answer. Although when i try to persist scope it doesn't pass any values to it. Although Jobs now adds correctly. Could be a problem with my scopeType form class. I've edited the original question so that is available now.

Comment: Can you make sure your query returns the values you expect ? You can do this by dumping the result or use the command : `app/console doctrine:query:dql [Your DQL query]`

Comment: Are you talking about the query from scopeType()? That is retrieving all the correct info. Here is what is being received by request in the profiler. I notice there is no Scope key just jobs key with the parameters `[
  jobNumber => 344, 
  scopes => [
    description => 1
  ], 
  description => From Web, 
  clients => 3, 
  company => 2, 
  _token => 3WjRHBY8VIroYSc2ldf6_LPtq1HsI00cRtbTcYar9SA
]`